# What symbol is used for 'proper distance'?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, notation, distance

Proper time and proper space are generally defined as what an observer would measure in their own rest frame. If $\tau$ is a commonly used symbol for the proper time, what is the corresponding symbol for proper space? That is, if $t$ is coordinate time and $t'$ is proper time and $x$ is distance, then what is $x'$ in the notation of $\tau$?

Answer (score 2):

There is no common convention that I know of.

I don't think there is a universal convention on prime-vs-unprimed.

In my experience, it is best to choose a notation and be very clear about what it means... using words, symbols, and a spacetime diagram. ("A spacetime diagram is worth a thousand words.")

Comment: "I don't think there is a universal convention on prime-vs-unprimed" Not asking for a universal convention, just a logical corollary. The descriptions are not the problem. The problem is that I've chosen the $\tau$ symbol for my proper time coordinate system, and now I want to talk about proper distance as an integral part of the metric (as distinct from the coordinate time and distance).

Comment: @QuarkSoup How about $\sigma$ (for $\sigma$pacelike, as opposed to $\tau$ for $\tau$imelike)?

Comment: I like it. and it's right next to $\tau$ in the alphabet. Nice symmetry.

Comment: I often use $L$ for proper length (for example, a ruler). I think a PHY 101 student would recognize it.

Comment: If you use $L$ for proper length, then what do you use for proper time?

Comment: I use $\tau$ for proper-time and $L$ for proper-length. (I use $\lambda$ for wavelength, and I use $\sigma$ for a sign option.) In the past, I have used $\ell$ for proper length.. but I think $L$ stands out better.

Comment: @robphy And it doesn't strike you as inconsistent to use one set of symbols for time and a completely different alphabet for space?

Comment: @QuarkSoup While they are logically not parallel, $L$ has been well established historically. So, my audience will likely have a better understanding of the physics when I use $L$, compared to $\sigma$.  (Some battles aren't worth fighting.... similarly, we use $B$ and $H$ for the magnetic field... and the electron-charge is negative.  One battle that I think is worth fighting is getting rid of "prime vs unprime".... I'd use more descriptive subscripts or superscripts.) ... my $0.02